# How to create a range based on moving data?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This is my first post on Stack Overflow for you VBA masterminds.

I'm working on a macro that imports data from a *.csv and performs various complex math activities and gives out a final "YES" or "NO" based on the data.

My issue is not being able to create a linear estimation based on a column only containing the last 48 hours of data.
 Presently I am using a hardcoded input to confirm the math checks out with what another source is saying.

```
=LINEST(Workspace!AL223:AL250,Workspace!AK223:AK250)
```

The issue that I am having is every time new data is imported, this function needs to only run on the column that I have data in.
The columns themselves hold blank cells prior to the time reference data.

What I need help with is a method in VBA to have a cell reference only the range where the data exists.

So my ultimate output would be to say something like...

```
Range("C100").value = "=LINEST(Workspace!$A$TopRow:$A$LastRow,Workspace!$B$TopRow:$B$LastRow)"
```

I'm not very familiar with VBA as far as configuring some SpecialCells, but what I believe would be nice is to have an if statement that would look at the entire column, then only pass the data into the LINEST statement. There's only blank cells (formulas that return " if not within 48hrs) and the values within 48 hours.

Comment: Take a look at special cells. You can reference only cells with values in a range for example.

Comment: The range im using however is dynamic and is updating every 5 minutes, is there a way to specifically have the function operate only within my 48 hour ceiling/floor references?

How could I have the function ignore blank cells all together?

Comment: What have you tried? There are countless references to finding the last row of data online? Are you stuck on something in particular or is there an additional complication?

Comment: I've tried so far to grab the row.count of the top and bottom rows and then concatenating them into a string to say something like A1:A5 and B1:B5 , then trying to pass those into the LINEST formula above.

Comment: @SJR The complication that I'm having is to have the function within the macro update to only reference the 'last 48 hours of data' which is kept in an indipendent columm. I have the appropriate checks to find what set of data is within 48 hours, but now need to capture the range of that data and put it into the formula.

Attempting to play with Special Cells now to get the range, no luck so far.

Right now I'm attempting to Sum a new range of data as practice, so for instance if I add in more data at the bottom, run the macro, it will include the new data as well.

Comment: OK, can you provide more details about the checks to find the set of data within the last 48 hours as that sounds like the key aspect. Is the issue that the time is in one column and you don't know how to relate that to another column (Offset might be of use here)?

Comment: Apologies, had a meeting.

The checks are on the tune of
A1 = IF(48 > (Total Time - Present Data Time) , Data, "" ) and this function is carried through the top row to my 'last row'

Comment: @SJR - I'm trying to find the range that my 48 hour data exists in (Lets call it TopRow to BottomRow) and then save that specific range of ATop:ABottom to be used as in the LINEST range.

Comment: I'm also trying to see about saving the actual ATop:ABottom range as a string and then giving that to the function.
Since a single cell will be given this 48hour LINEST(RangeA,RangeB).

Concatenating the Column Name with the Row number and then feeding that to a reference doesnt work either. So something basic like having B1 = A1 doesnt work, as the result I'm getting is that B1 = "A1" (inputted as text and not the value stored in A1)

Sorry if I'm making it sound different. This is the final part of my Macro and it's kicking me for the past 2 hours.

Comment: If a string variable `s` has the value "A1" then `Range(s)` will refer to the cell A1. If you have two string variables you can use `Range(s1 & ":" & s2)`.

Comment: @SJR I've tried this previously but the string doesnt work as a range how I would like. Could you please submit an answer/ code that shows me its working?

`Range("C1").value = "=LINEST($A$TopRow:$A$LastRow,$B$TopRow:$B$LastRow)"`

`TopRow = Range("A"&s1&":"&"A"&"s2)`

Comment: So, see below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this isn't really an answer but I can't post it in a comment. See if this is the sort of thing you need. You have to build up the string, ensuring the variables are removed from the quotes as otherwise they will be interpreted literally.

```
Sub x()

Dim TopRow As Long, LastRow As Long

TopRow = 10
LastRow = 250

Range("C1").Formula = "=LINEST($A$" & TopRow & ":$A$" & LastRow & ",$B$" & TopRow & ":$B$" & LastRow & ")"

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesnt appear to be working for me. The strings arent taking in the values. Can we pass a string type into the function to read as a range?
`TopRow = Cells(19, "AA").Value
Range("C1").Formula = "=LINEST($AL$ & TopRow & :$AL$ & LastRow ,$AK$ & TopRow & :$AK$ & LastRow)"`


What you've given me is my original though on how to get this enacted. Passing strings in as the actual fillers. That way the strings build themselves everytime the Macro is instanced.

Any and all more help is much appreciated. Can I Tip you on here?

Comment: If the contents of AA19 is a valid cell address then you could use that. You can vote things up using the arrows on the left. But you would need four variables